# Managing relationship creation and deletion in a REST API

Tags: rest

We are building a REST API with the following resources: Users, UserGroups. Currently we are supporting the following URI's:

```
/BASEAPI/VERSION/Users/
/BASEAPI/VERSION/Users/{id}/UserGroups
/BASEAPI/VERSION/UserGroups/
/BASEAPI/VERSION/UserGroups/{id}/Users
```

I like this better than including references in the objects which then have to be pulled on subsequent requests. It also means that we can avoid query params to filter the results. i.e. we don't have to support:

```
/BASEAPI/VERSION/UserGroups/{id}?user_id={user_id}
```

The problem is that it doesn't make creation and deletion semantics very clear. i.e. should a DELETE request to:

/BASEAPI/VERSION/Users/{id}/UserGroups/{group_id}

remove the UserGroup, or remove the user from the user group?

We've considered adding:

/BASEAPI/VERSION/UserGroupUsers

But something doesn't quite feel right about that, but maybe it's the best way to go. What do others think are best practices?

Comment: What is the value add by not using query parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out how you intend to represent the membership relationship between user and user group. It can be an attribute of the user, an attribute of the group, or a separate resource. Those are the only choices. How users are added to and removed from groups falls out naturally from your choice. Membership management becomes a PUT/DELETE to the user, the group, or the membership resource.

Personally, I find the separate resource to be the cleanest way to handle the issue, but you then need query parameters to poll for a specific user or group. Also, you'd need to change your second-level resource names, because it makes no sense for `/userGroups/{id}/users` to return a collection of `userGroupUsers` resources.

Answer (score 1):

A URL addresses a resource. A `GET` on this URL returns the resource and a `DELETE` deletes it. If the `DELETE` would delete something different than the `GET` is returning something really is broken.

So if `/BASEAPI/VERSION/Users/4711/UserGroups` would return the UserGroups with the ID 0815 and 0816 the `DELETE` should delete both userGroups.

Question is: Does this make sense? What is happening to the other users in both userGroups?

If you want to remove a user from a group I would provide a `PATCH` Method.

Comment: I'm leaning towards sticking with the convention that you discuss. This does mean that we're probably going to have to add UserGroupUsers as a separate resource and move to query parameters instead of putting the relationships into the URIs themselves.

Comment: You can do both but to make it clearer: I think your problem is the DELETE not the URL. If user foo should not be member of group bar anymore I would either update foo or bar - depending on who holds the reference. After the operation both resources are still alive because you just removed a relation - you did not delete a resource.